# Does Spartan/Edge from Windows 10 use the same rendering engine with IE11?

Tags: browsers, internet-explorer, windows-8

I decided to test the website I'm working on now in older versions of IE (such as IE 6, 7, 8) using the IE Developer Tools aka F12. When I opened the Emulation tab in the Dev Tools dialog to set the document mode, I saw that we do not have different options for IE11 and Edge:

[image]

Does it mean that IE11 and the newest browser from Microsoft, Edge, use the same rendering engine? Or does it mean that the IE11 rendering engine has been updated through the Windows update automatically so even in Windows 8.1 in IE11 we are already using the newest rendering engine from Spartan/Edge from Windows 10?

Comment: It is my understanding that its a whole new engine, as they believe that Internet Explorer has run its course and they even admitted they haven't be able to get people to return to IE due to bad reputation in the past.

Answer (score 2):

ZDNet posted on 29th December that

> Spartan is still going to use Microsoft's Chakra JavaScript engine and
>   Microsoft's Trident rendering engine (not WebKit or gecko), Sources say.

Source : http://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-is-building-a-new-browser-as-part-of-its-windows-10-push/

So it is the same engine polished a little. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 1):

When I first read about this, it seemed to me, too, that Microsoft might actually be getting their act together and producing a responsible browser but didn't understand how they could use the same internal engines, as noted by @ivxenog, to accomplish a "new" browser. After more study, I realized that Microsoft is only taking IE and removing the old, legacy "cruft" and rebranding it as "Edge". Any new features, properties, elements, functionality are only items that would have made their way into future versions of IE anyway.

One method to find this out is the preponderance of footnotes in caniuse.com which state "Under consideration" or not implemented for Edge in the same quantity or history as for IE.

My point then is, the only difference between IE and Edge is that Edge will not contain support for remnants of old IE and old Windows needs and remains, essentially, IE as it is today: not very good: http://html6test.com/results/desktop.html